# Should I use Laravel's collective Form or traditional html form? Which is better?

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I'm a novice in `Laravel` development. I'm learning about `Form`. But I'm not understanding why i need to learn again about `Form for Laravel` as i know how to use `form in pure html`.  I'm confused about that should i use laravel's  `collective form` or `Pure Html Form`? Which is better?

Answer (score 6):

I find collective to be more useful in two ways.

1) Using Laravel collective gives CSRF protection automatically by including hidden field with a security token as a form element which traditional html form does not and you have do that manually by using `{{ csrf_field() }}`. Not including is erroneous.

2) When updating the database info, `Form::model()` to bind the data to form fields and makes it way easier to populate the form fields with the data to be edited like auto checking checkboxes etc. which saves quite a overhead.

Comment: I agree. The "old" input handling when there are validation errors is reason alone to use the form helpers.

Comment: but it's harder to learn than `pure html`. Also i can't customize it(`laravel collective html`) as pure html. what about that ? Also the `{{csrf_field()}}` can be included in a form very easily in pure html too by that command, so why will i use `collective`? @ceejayoz @notme

Comment: @smkpobon It's up to you. You asked for opinions, and got opinions.